# I want to use css to control video tag's width and height

Tags: html, css

This is my result so far.
[link](http://140.115.51.88/~shawn/bootstrap-3.3.2/test.html)

I set video tag's width and height are 100%.
But in the webpage I find the video tag is bigger than 100%.

I don't know why it becomes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for responsive video.  You need to create a container, and then run the video in a child element (such as an iframe):

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; 
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Good tutorial [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I just want to know what mistake that I make. ><"

Comment: The video is not a square.  You have set `min-height` to 100% - so the width will always be greater than 100%.  Try removing `min-height` and see what happens.

Comment: I already set object-fit to cover and I think the video will fit the size that I set. I also try remove min-height or change it to height, but the height is still higher than that I expect.